# Is there a limit to nicotine tolerance?

Tags: drug-tolerance, nicotine

Is there a limit to how much of a nicotine tolerance you can have, or does it endlessly go on and get stronger?

Edit: What I mean is whether or not there is a point to the human nicotine tolerance, whereas in the consuming of nicotine products, you still get a buzz as there is no higher level to nicotine tolerance that may be achieved.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! What "gets stronger"? Also, are you talking about human smoking nicotine? I am not sure I understand the notion of tolerance in your post.

Comment: agree with Remi above - this should likely be moved to Health.SE

Comment: ...but should be clarified before. In its current form, the question would probably be closed on Health.SE also. I am voting to close here as unclear.

Comment: Question has been edited.